# mac os x start a daemon after boot completed

Tags: macos

I'm using this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/hzorha/Downloads/trunk/build/g5/macos/src/bin/g5/test</string>
        </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

test is the name of the binary.

And I've placed it in /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.test.plist

What am I doing wrong, because it does not start when the computer boots.

Comment: Is it owned by `root` with only owner `write` permissions?

Comment: Also do you have any issues brining it up with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.test.plist` I also notice you are storing the item being launched in your home dir... Im not sure if that is going to work, I've never tried that - you may need to use a user level LaunchAgent instead, or attempt to move your codebase to somewhere global.

Comment: yes that was the problem, the plist was not own by root, but by my user. thx.

Comment: if you want you can post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `launchctl` man page for the `load` and `unload` subcommands:

```
Load the specified configuration files or directories of configuration
files.  Jobs that are not on-demand will be started as soon as possible. All
specified jobs will be loaded before any of them are allowed to start. Note
that per-user configuration files (LaunchAgents) must be owned by root (if
they are located in /Library/LaunchAgents) or the user loading them (if they
are located in $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents).  All system-wide daemons
(LaunchDaemons) must be owned by root. Configuration files must disallow
group and world writes. These restrictions are in place for security rea-
sons, as allowing writability to a launchd configuration file allows one to
specify which executable will be launched.

Note that allowing non-root write access to the
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons directory WILL render your system unbootable.
```